TypeScript type error on my servfer action next.js
need help on a server action on my Next.js applicastion, giving me a type error and can't pinpoint the reason, it appears when there are 3 values on the db.insert for the orderProduct and it always errors out the first value whatever it field it is.
create-order.tsx
products.map(async ({ productId, quantity, variantId }) => {
  await db.insert(orderProduct).values({
    productVariantId: variantId,
    productId: productId,
    quantity,
    orderId: order[0].id,
  })
})

schema
export const orderProduct = pgTable('order_product', {
  id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
  quantity: integer('quantity').notNull(),
  productVariantId: serial('productVariantId')
    .notNull()
    .references(() => productVariants.id, { onDelete: 'cascade' }),
  productId: serial('productId')
    .notNull()
    .references(() => products.id, { onDelete: 'cascade' }),
  orderId: serial('orderId')
    .notNull()
    .references(() => orders.id, { onDelete: 'cascade' }),
})

Types
import * as z from 'zod'

export const createOrderSchema = z.object({
  total: z.number(),
  status: z.string(),
  paymentIntentId: z.string(),
  products: z.array(
    z.object({
      quantity: z.number(),
      productId: z.string(),
      variantId: z.string(),
    }),
  ),
})

Error message
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(values: { quantity: number | SQL<unknown> | Placeholder<string, any>; id?: number | SQL<unknown> | Placeholder<string, any> | undefined; productId?: number | SQL<...> | Placeholder<...> | undefined; productVariantId?: number | ... 2 more ... | undefined; orderId?: number | ... 2 more ... | undefined; }[]): PgInsertBase<...>', gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'productVariantId' does not exist in type '{ quantity: number | SQL<unknown> | Placeholder<string, any>; id?: number | SQL<unknown> | Placeholder<string, any> | undefined; productId?: number | SQL<...> | Placeholder<...> | undefined; productVariantId?: number | ... 2 more ... | undefined; orderId?: number | ... 2 more ... | undefined; }[]'.ts(2769)

Here's the error, it will be the same if i move around the values of my db.insert

It looks like the error is telling you values() takes an array of objects, not an object

Do you know what's causing this? I'm using drizzle as my orm and insert takes an object not an array.

Found the answer, on my types it should be z.number() instead of z.string() for the productId and variantId
import * as z from 'zod'

export const createOrderSchema = z.object({
  total: z.number(),
  status: z.string(),
  paymentIntentId: z.string(),
  products: z.array(
    z.object({
      quantity: z.number(),
      productId: z.number(),
      variantId: z.number(),
    }),
  ),
})


Modular Design:

Always define base schemas (DbProductSchema, DbOrderSchema) to ensure
a single source of truth for common fields.
Use extend, pick, or omit methods to customize schemas for specific
use cases.

Schema Naming Conventions:

Use Db as a prefix for base schemas that represent database
structures (e.g., DbProductSchema).
Use descriptive names like    create, read, update, or basic for
specific operation schemas.


order-product.schema.ts

import * as z from 'zod';

// Base schema for a product. Reused for consistency across operations.
const DbProductOrderSchema = z.object({
  productId: z.number(),
  quantity: z.number(),
  variantId: z.number(),
});

// Specific schemas for product operations like creation, reading, or basic use cases.
export const OrderProductSchema = {
  create: DbProductOrderSchema,
  read: DbProductOrderSchema.extend({
    id: z.string().uuid(), // Includes unique ID for identification
  }),
};


order.schema.ts

import * as z from 'zod';
import { OrderProductSchema } from './order-product.schema'; // Import product schema for reusability

// Base schema for order data. Includes products using the basic ProductSchema.
const DbOrderSchema = z.object({
  total: z.number(),
  status: z.string(),
  paymentIntentId: z.string(),
  orderDate: z.date(),
  products: z.array(OrderProductSchema.create), // Ensures products conform to the basic schema
});

// Specific schemas for order operations like creation and reading.
export const OrderSchema = {
  create: DbOrderSchema.omit({ orderDate: true }).extend({
    orderDate: z.coerce.date(), // String needs to be coerced to date
  }), // Used for creating new orders
  read: DbOrderSchema.extend({
    id: z.string().uuid(), // Includes unique ID for order identification
  }),
};

This will assist you in managing any type of project. I've included an example for a date. In the same way, you can add product schema.
